# Stop infinite function in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have put together a GUI which searches for a specific subject matter in your email within a while loop and continues to do so until it finds an unread message with that subject. Once it finds that email, it does some other functions and when all those functions are complete, it loops back to the beginning and searches once again for an unread message containing that subject. I am wanting to implement a "stop" button which will allow the user to break out of this infinite loop of search the inbox but I've had no success and am unsure on how to tackle this problem.  I have tried searching for comparable examples but have been unable to implement them to my specific situation. I've truncated the code as much as possible to still allow for interpretation.

```
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent       
        self.desktop_path = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'],'Desktop')


        #create labelframe for directory and browse button
        label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="  Search Inbox:")
        label_frame.grid(row=1, columnspan=15, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)        

        #create label frame for send report and button
        label_frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="  Interrupt Search:")
        label_frame2.grid(row=2, columnspan=15, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        #create label frame for send report and button
        self.label_frame3 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="  Totals:")
        self.label_frame3.grid(row=3, columnspan=15, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        #create browse button and place on grid
        label_frame.button = ttk.Button(label_frame, text="Start",command=self.start, width=8)
        label_frame.button.grid(row=4, column=7, sticky="EW", padx=100, ipadx=10)

        #create send report button and place on grid
        label_frame2.button = ttk.Button(label_frame2, text='Stop', command=self.stop, width=8)
        label_frame2.button.grid(row=4, column=7, sticky='EW', padx=100, ipadx=10)

        self.label_frame3.entry = tk.Entry(self.label_frame3)
        self.label_frame3.entry.grid(row=4, column=7, stick='W', padx=50, ipadx=25)




    def SaveAttachments(self, subject='subject matter goes here'):
        #create outlook application object
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)  #create an inbox object
        messages = inbox.Items #create a message object


        try:
            inbox.Folders.Add('Extracts')  #create folder in inbox, if already exsists, nothing happens.
        except:
            pass



        #iterate through messages to find message that matches subject and is unread
        for message in messages:
            if message.Subject == subject and message.Unread:
                    attachments = message.Attachments 
                    attachment = attachments.Item(1)
                    for attachment in message.Attachments:
                        if not os.path.isdir(self.desktop_path):  #check if the path exsists, and if it doesn't, create it
                            os.makedirs(self.desktop_path)
                        attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(self.desktop_path, str(attachment)))
                        if message.Subject == subject and message.Unread:
                            message.Unread = False  #change message status from unread to read
                        message.Move(inbox.Folders('Extracts'))  #move read messages to Extracts Folder
                        #print(attachment)    
                        break
            else:
                attachment = None

        return os.path.join(self.desktop_path, str(attachment))




    def start(self, event=None):
        self.cancel_id = None
        self.main()

    def main(self, event=None):
        variable = True
        while variable:
            file = self.SaveAttachments()
            if 'None' not in file:
                variable = False
                self.CreatePivots(file)
                self.CreateExcel()
                self.SendEmail()
                self.label_frame3.entry.delete(0, 'end')
                self.label_frame3.entry.insert(0, f'{self.table.iloc[-1,0]}')
                self.cancel_id = self.label_frame3.entry.after(1000, self.main)
                variable = True


    def stop(self, event=None):
         if self.cancel_id is not None:
            self.label_frame3.entry.after_cancel(self.cancel_id)
            self.cancel_id = None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something liket this using threading.
This is the simplest example that comes to my mind for reproduce the behaviour that you want

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading as th
import time

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.run = True
        self.counter = 0

    def build(self):
        self.counter_label = tk.Label(text=self.counter)
        self.counter_label.pack()

        self.stop_button = tk.Button(text='stop', command=self.stop_counter)
        self.stop_button.pack()

    def start_counter(self):
        while self.run:
            self.counter += 1
            self.counter_label.configure(text=self.counter)
            time.sleep(1)

    def run_counter(self):
        self.my_thread = th.Thread(target=self.start_counter) # create new thread that runs the self.start_counter() function
        self.my_thread.start() # start the threading 

    def stop_counter(self):
        self.counter_label.configure(text="counter stopped")
        self.run = False # set the variable to false so that the while loop inside the threading stops
        self.my_thread.join() # this destoy the created threading

    def start_loop(self):
        self.root.mainloop() # starts the tkinter mainloop

app = App()
app.build()

app.run_counter()

app.start_loop()
```

By the way, its better to call the variables with a significant name that will help you remind for what they are used.

Comment: I have tried to place “variable=True” as a class attribute under __init__ as you suggested however I am still having the same issue. Once I hit the “start” button, the GUI freezes since the while loop has commenced and I am unable to click on the “stop” button to interrupt the while loop. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: have you added the `self.` before the variable name name?

Comment: @GeeSama another option is to implement [threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) in your code

Comment: Yes I used self.variable in order for both functions to have access to it. I am unfamiliar with threading as I’ve never used it before, do I thread the start function? The stop function ? Or both ? Sorry for so many questions but I am completely stumped here.

Comment: i've update the answer whit an example of threading. You are right the previous answer didn't work.

Comment: After much revision to my original code and utilizing your threading example as a template, I was able to achieve the results I was looking for. At first I was having a lot of difficulty trying to incorporate your threading example with my existing code since my class inherited from tk.Frame so I used your example as a template and re-wrote my code to fit that structure and it works perfectly now. Thank you

Comment: Glad that it helped